# How do you add attributes to tags with Zen Coding Package in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext

I get how to add HTML nodes w/ST2 -> if I want a row with 4 cells "tr>td*4(tab)" but how do you add something like "valign="top"" in the td's. Same with adding a link a(tab) how would you add the target attribute in something like a(target="_blank")*9.

Appreciate any advice

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try these,

`div[title], a[title="Hello world" rel], td[colspan=2]`

The example I have given is found here - http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/

Comment: Thanks, its a great app and I really appreciate the help, esp the link.